# Adding a taxonomy drop down to drupal search

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to add a drop-down containing taxonomy terms to my site's basic search. I have created a taxonomy term *category* and used search auto-complete module for providing auto-complete search functionality. Can anyone suggest me how to add taxonomy drop-down besides the search button on the search block and relate the drop-down selection with search text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to use [custom search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module. For auto-complete feature i think it is better to go with custom development rather than depending on contributed modules which will come with lot of unwanted features.

To preface :

You will need to use `hook_form_alter()` for add you custom field. 
Then with the help of `hook_search` you can inject your custom search criteria using search query extract and search query insert.